# Display Internet Options like Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, wpf, system.diagnostics

I am displaying Internet Options in my Web Browser control using the following code:

```
Process.Start("InetCpl.Cpl");
```

However, this creates a new window for Internet Options that is independent of my MainWindow.

I need to display Internet options like Internet Explorer i.e. the MainWindow UI should be blocked and Internet options window should open inside the MainWindow.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normally you would use "Process p = Process.Start("Notepad.exe"); p.EnableRaisingEvents = true; p.Exited += new EventHandler(p_Exited);" But this does not work for Control Panel apps as the Exited event gets fired as soon as the process is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may try to invoke the launch function directly.
Import the launch function into your class

```
[DllImport("inetcpl.cpl", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern int LaunchInternetControlPanel(IntPtr hWnd);
```

and call it from your command

```
LaunchInternetControlPanel(this.Handle);
```